# Write app for ios with cordova(or titanium) without mac decive

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium

i am android and web programmer and i want write  my program for apple mobiles. i want use Cordova(or titanium) but i don't have mac device.

is it possible? 
sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible using this site [Phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) You can write code once and build it for different platforms. Don't know about titanium.

Comment: how get certificate and test Ios programs without mac device?

Comment: I haven't use it, just know that it's possible through that site. have a look http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html#_windows_users

Comment: this link is very good. thanks;)